# Is there a way to monitor the state of an internal signal with a University Program VWF in Quartus 13.1?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, hdl, quartus

I have a VHDL finite statemachine. I created a internal `TYPE` akin to `TYPE t_SM_Main IS (s_Idle, s_Start, s_TX1, s_TX0, s_Cleanup);` I have also created a University Program VWF inside Quartus for the simulated response of my VHDL code.

Is it possible to have a signal that is defined inside the `ARCHITECTURE` be visible to the simulator without it being exported using the `ENTITY` `PORT` map? (which would also pose a problem because the `TYPE` definition needs to precede the `PORT` definition.)

Another way of phrasing it is that I'm wondering if there is a way to see the `ENTITY` not as a black box but as a white box.

I'm using Quartus II 64-bit 13.1 without any newer revisions of VHDL enabled.

**update**
Seeing as `variable` is a better option as per the ["’two-process’ design method"](https://www.gaisler.com/doc/vhdl2proc.pdf). Is it possible to get the state of a `variable` inside a University Program VWF?

Comment: `Edit` > `Insert Node or Bus` > `Node Finder...` > change Filter to `Design Entry (all names)` > choose signals you want

Comment: Please add that as an answer so I can upvote/accept it when it indeed works (I'm going to check tonight +4hrs)

Comment: @Qiu (forgot to mention you.) Please add as an answer so I can accept and upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Simulation Waveform Editor select:

1. `Edit` > `Insert Node or Bus`

[image: Insert Node or Bus]

2. `Node Finder...`

[image: Node finder]

3. in a new window that popęd up, change Filter to `Design Entry (all names)` (default: `Pins: all`)

[image: Filter]

4. list signals and choose those that you want to analyze.

*Pictures taken from [Quartus II Tutorial](http://denethor.wlu.ca/quartus/index.shtml)*